# How to make Flutter app font size independent from device settings?

Tags: flutter, settings, font-size

I needed to make my entire app independed from device's font size settings. I found that I could set `textScaleFactor: 1.0` for every text view manualy. It's a good solution for a few Text widgets, but not good for a big app with dozens of Text widgets.

Comment: The ```MaterialApp``` has a ```theme``` attribute, you can customise it and it will be applied to all widgets enclosed in your material app. It will be a bit tricky to find out which attribute is used for every widget but it's doable :).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

First things first I have to say that it's a bad idea to make your text irrelevant to phone settings. It makes your app less friendly for users with disabilities such as blindness or motor impairment. As a developer you should make sure your layout has enough room to render all it's contents when the font sizes are increased. But sometimes we actualy need font size to be fixed.

All you have to do is create Material App Builder to set Media Query property "textScaleFactor: 1.0" for the entire app.

```
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      child: child,
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
    );
   },
)
```

Solution was found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22480#issuecomment-425720215).

Comment: this does not work on assesibility settings

Comment: How does this work if you don't supply a builder and instead use the 'home' parameter for my MaterialApp?

Comment: Problem with this approach is you are losing user experience, user might need to change font size for his/her vision problem but you are limiting him to use the same font size you gave. You can follow @Pratik Butani  answers for this situation.

Comment: For Null Safety use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73937338/13601462)

Comment: textScaleFactor is deprecated.
Use textScaler,  
MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(1.0)),

Comment: This answer is outdated. Simply use `MediaQuery.withNoTextScaling(child: child!)`

Answer (score 52):

You are right [Oleksandr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10713044/oleksandr), Setting the textScaleFactor to 1.0 and calling it a day means ignoring your user's needs. They’re asking for a bigger text size and you are not delivering it.

**Let's make it more adaptive**

You can choose minimum factor and maximum factor and that you can give comparatively.

```
return MaterialApp(
        builder: (context, child) {
          final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
          final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaleFactor.clamp(1.0, 1.3);
          return MediaQuery(
            child: child,
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: scale),
          );
        },
);
```

Instead of a hardcoded **textScaleFactor**, we can give a constrained system value.

By using **clamp()**, we're giving the system **textScaleFactor** a lower and upper bound.

Source : [Restricting system textScaleFactor, when you have to](https://iiro.dev/2020/05/18/restricting-system-text-scale-factor/)

**Update Flutter 3.16.9**

'textScaleFactor' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use textScaler instead. Use of textScaleFactor was deprecated in preparation for the upcoming nonlinear text scaling support. This feature was deprecated after v3.12.0-2.0.pre.

```dart
MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    // Retrieve the MediaQueryData from the current context.
    final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);

    // Calculate the scaled text factor using the clamp function to ensure it stays within a specified range.
    final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaler.clamp(
      minScaleFactor: 1.0, // Minimum scale factor allowed.
      maxScaleFactor: 1.3, // Maximum scale factor allowed.
    );

    // Create a new MediaQueryData with the updated text scaling factor.
    // This will override the existing text scaling factor in the MediaQuery.
    // This ensures that text within this subtree is scaled according to the calculated scale factor.
    return MediaQuery(
      // Copy the original MediaQueryData and replace the textScaler with the calculated scale.
      data: mediaQueryData.copyWith(
        textScaler: scale,
      ),
      // Pass the original child widget to maintain the widget hierarchy.
      child: child!,
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Wait where does this go? what is `child`

Comment: ```child``` is the widget here.

Comment: This is the perfect way to manage this Font size adaptive issue without losing user experience.

Comment: @Mdomerarafat Only partially. You'd clamp the value in a way that still is adequate to your boundaries, but if the client is almost blind and uses massive font sizes, text will still be too small. But agreed, this is better than forcing `1.0` scale factor.

Answer (score 5):

**Here the simple solution to prevent breaking UI when change device font settings**

> Use this code for solution inside the main.dart under Material app

```
 builder: (context, child) {
              return MediaQuery(
                data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
                child: child,
              );
            },
```

> Here the sample code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'App Title',
        theme: theme(),
        initialRoute: SplashScreen.routeName,
        routes: routes,
        ///Here the code for prevent font size when change mobile
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
            child: child,
          );
        },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This Is working in my Project

```
return MaterialApp(
      home:Container(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          child: child!,
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        );
      },
    );
```

With Getx

```
GetMaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: AppColor().colorPrimary),
              translations: LocaleString(),
              navigatorKey:navigatorKey,
              locale:
                  Locale(Utils.language.value, Utils.language_country.value),
              routes: Routes.getRoutes(),
                builder:(context,child){
                  return MediaQuery(data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0), child: child);
                }
            );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Container(child: SplashScreen()),
          builder: (context, child) {
            return MediaQuery(
              child: child!,
              data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The [@Pratik Butani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66668724/6715678) Answer is absolutely right. But
If you are returning `GetMaterialApp` or any other widget. Remember the `builder` must be in bottom.

```
 return GetMaterialApp(

      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.aBeeZeeTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme
        )
      ),

      initialBinding: MainBinding(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: Routes.splashRoute,
      getPages: Routes.routes,

        builder:(context,child){
        final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
        final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaleFactor.clamp(0.8, 0.9);
          return MediaQuery(data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: scale), child: child!);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this old thread, note regarding all of the above solutions referencing textScaleFactor: **textScaleFactor has recently been deprecated** (as of November 15, 2023's Flutter v. 3.16 release, I believe). For details, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/deprecate-textscalefactor

Comment: Hi @Parthish -- I don't have any additional details to share, but I thought it was important to highlight to anyone coming across this old thread that ALL of the existing answers utilize the recently deprecated "textScaleFactor" instead of its replacement, TextScaler, and therefore it would not be a good idea to rely on those earlier answers. I provided an official link describing this deprecation that includes migration examples. I am not sure what could be clearer or what other details should be included. but I am open to suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create Material App Builder to set Media Query property "textScaleFactor: 1.0" for the entire app. This works on my app:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) 
{
    return MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, MediaQuery's `textScaleFactor` is now deprecated in favor of new `MediaQueryData.textScaler` parameter.

Additionally, MediaQuery now makes this easy by providing a static method `withNoTextScaling` to automatically wrap the child in a `MediaQuery` with no text scaling.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
        child: MediaQuery.withNoTextScaling(child: const ActualChild()),
       );
```

There is also a `withClampedTextScaling` method that allows you to clamp the possible text scaling factors into a possible range:

```dart
return MaterialApp(
        child: MediaQuery.withClampedTextScaling(
          minScaleFactor: 0.8,
          maxScaleFactor: 1.2,
          child: const ActualChild(),
        ),
       );
```