# Prevent changing text size based device screen size Flutter

Tags: flutter, size, screen

Iam using textScaleFactor in every Text widget in Flutter, but if the user change the display or font size from device settings. it change the size for all Text widgets of the whole app.

Is there any way to prevent listening to text sizes in the device settings from main function, MaterialApp or ThemeData?

I dont want to use MediaQuery because my app is very big and I cannot change every Text widget right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can override the the text scale factor provided by the system like this:

```
MaterialApp(
  builder:  (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0, ), //set desired text scale factor here
      child: child,
    );
  },
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
```

[Source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19707)

This overrides the system text scale factor in your whole application to the factor you choose.

But this is a really bad practice. You should not rely on overriding system / accessibility setting to fix your ui. There are a lot of devices with a lot of form factors, screen resolutions, densities etc. The right way to approach this problem is to create a responsive ui, that can scale well for different screens, and settings. A good starting point is the [official flutter site](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive) for responsive ui, and the [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package, that can save you a lot of trouble scaling texts.

Comment: Thanks, all widgets work well, but my problem is only with the text size in screen different sizes. Do you know if Flutter 2.0.0 has a new features to support text size?

Comment: I have facing this error `the argument type 'MediaQuery Function(BuildContext, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)?`

Comment: Just write "child: child!"

Answer (score 5):

For null safety use this code:

```
MaterialApp(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: data.copyWith(
              textScaleFactor: 1.0),
          child: child!,  
        );
    },
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that child would never be null? In that case why argument type is `Widget?`?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this question or tested the case? I am using MaterialApp.router widget to provide a GoRouter config and using "child!". I've not got an error so far but a little bit worried to use null coalescing.

Answer (score 1):

In 2024 and later, you can use **textScaler** instered of using **textScaleFactor** (*deprecated*).

```
MaterialApp(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data:  MediaQuery.of(context)
                .copyWith(textScaler: const TextScaler.linear(1.0)),
          child: child!,  
        );
    },
    title: 'Flutter Demo',
    home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its implementation is a bit confusing. It takes 'child' as a parameter, for null safety we should add '!' to the end. Just need to add this part inside main.dart and it will apply to all the app pages. Full working code example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
            textScaleFactor: 1.0,
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     
      theme: ThemeData(
     
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      title: 'My Shiny App',

      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

And if you prefer you can set min and max scale for it which is recommended way of doing this, like below:

```
 return MaterialApp(
              builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
final myMediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);        
final definedScaleRange = mediaQueryData.textScaleFactor.clamp(0.5, 1.2);

                return MediaQuery(
                    data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: definedScaleRange),
                  ),
                  child: child!,
                );
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two criteria to answering this question properly:

1. Over-ride any user text size settings on the device.
2. Don't use MediaQuery.of(context) because this forces excessive builds.

This solution solves both the text size and rebuild issues.  Use this at the start of your app.  The MediaQuery widget doesn't force extra builds:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  MediaQueryData windowData = MediaQueryData.fromView(View.of(context));
  windowData = windowData.copyWith(
    textScaleFactor: 1.0, //or whatever you want
  );
  return MediaQuery(
    data: windowData,
    child: MaterialApp(
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,  //if you need it
      //...
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, child) {
    //ignore system scale factor
    return MediaQuery(
      data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
        textScaleFactor: 1.0,
      ),
      child: child ?? Container(),
    );
  },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).