Get every Row in a Column to be the height of the tallest Row (using IntrinsicHeight at the moment)
I've been working on this issue for a few hours and I might just be missing something very simple.
I have a Column widget that will (at most) have 3 IconButtonRow widgets (a custom widget  I made). The only issue with the way that I had it set up previously was that these IconButtonRows could have different heights, resulting in the "grid" that I'm creating to look a bit ugly (see how green row is shorter than red row)

I've been trying to use IntrinsicHeight and wrap the outermost Column with that in order to basically say: "get the height of the tallest IconButtonRow and ensure that all the other IconButtonRows are that height as well" but to no avail. First image below shows the widget tree as it currently stands, the second and third shows proof of the two rows having different heights.



Code snippets
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        var isMobileWidth = constraints.maxWidth < 600;
        return Consumer<FavoriteCommonTasksService>(
          builder: (context, favoriteCommonTasksService, child) {
            // ...

            // Creates icon button rows based on the favorited common tasks + the required
            List<Widget> columnWidgets = getColumnWidgets(
              commonTasksForGrid: commonTasksForGrid,
              context: context,
              allCommonTasks: allCommonTasks,
              isMobileWidth: isMobileWidth,
            );

            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: columnWidgets,
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

List<Widget> getColumnWidgets({
    required List<CommonTasks> commonTasksForGrid,
    required BuildContext context,
    required List<CommonTasks> allCommonTasks,
    bool isMobileWidth = false,
  }) {
    List<Widget> columnWidgets = [];

    // Common tasks header + edit pencil
    ...

    // Column with three IconButtonRows
    List<Widget> iconButtonRows = [];
    List<String> rowTitles = [];
    List<IconData> rowIcons = [];
    List<String> rowUrls = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < commonTasksForGrid.length; i++) {
      // Removes the "(Required)" from displaying on the grid
      String iconName;
      if (commonTasksForGrid[i].iconName.contains("(Required)")) {
        iconName = commonTasksForGrid[i].iconName.replaceAll("(Required)", "");
      } else {
        iconName = commonTasksForGrid[i].iconName;
      }

      rowTitles.add(iconName);
      rowIcons.add(materialIcons[commonTasksForGrid[i].materialIcon]!);
      rowUrls.add(commonTasksForGrid[i].linkUrl);

      // If we have a complete row or it's the last item, add the row to favoriteCommonTasks
      if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 || i == commonTasksForGrid.length - 1) {
        iconButtonRows.add(
          IconButtonRow(
            titles: List.from(rowTitles),
            icons: List.from(rowIcons),
            urls: List.from(rowUrls),
          ),
        );

        // columnWidgets.add(const SizedBox(height: 16));

        // Reset the row lists for the next row
        rowTitles.clear();
        rowIcons.clear();
        rowUrls.clear();
      }
    }

    columnWidgets.add(
      IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: iconButtonRows,
        ),
      ),
    );
    return columnWidgets;
  }

IconButtonRow
class IconButtonRow extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The button titles.
  final List<String> titles;

  /// The button icons.
  final List<IconData> icons;

  /// The button urls.
  final List<String> urls;

  /// The maximum number of items.
  static const int maxItems = 3;

  const IconButtonRow({
    super.key,
    required this.titles,
    required this.icons,
    required this.urls,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // 32 for the 16 horizontal padding that we have for the pages
    final double buttonContainerWidth = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 48) / maxItems;
    List<Widget> buttons = [];
    if (titles.length != icons.length || titles.length != urls.length) {
      throw Exception('Must have the same number of titles, icons, and urls');
    } else if (titles.length > maxItems) {
      throw Exception(
          "Can only have $maxItems items in each row. Attempting to include ${titles.length}");
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        buttons.add(
          CircularIconButton(
            title: titles[i],
            icon: icons[i],
            url: urls[i],
            containerWidth: buttonContainerWidth,
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    while (buttons.length < maxItems) {
      buttons.add(SizedBox(width: buttonContainerWidth));
    }

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: buttons,
    );
  }
}

CircularIconButton
class CircularIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The button title.
  final String title;

  /// The button icon.
  final IconData icon;

  /// The url to link to.
  final String url;

  /// The width of the button container.
  final double containerWidth;

  /// The height of the button.
  static const double buttonHeight = 100;

  const CircularIconButton({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.icon,
    required this.url,
    required this.containerWidth,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var isMobileWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 600;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
          throw Exception('Could not launch ${Uri.parse(url)}');
        }
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: containerWidth,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: buttonHeight,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
                    throw Exception('Could not launch ${Uri.parse(url)}');
                  }
                },
                style: primaryButtonStyle.copyWith(
                  shape: WidgetStateProperty.all<CircleBorder>(
                      const CircleBorder()),
                ),
                child: Icon(icon),
              ),
            ),
            // The title of the button.
            Text(
              title,
              softWrap: true,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 3,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: isMobileWidth
                  ? bodyRegular.copyWith(color: ftiDarkGray)
                  : bodyRegular.copyWith(color: ftiDarkGray, fontSize: 24),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Provide the code snippet for better understanding. On first thought, it seems like you are trying to get each item of grid have a fixed height. If that is the case, you need something else. If you are using GridView, try with childAspectRatio. This will give the items a fixed height.

@Neil-NotNeo Went ahead and edited the post to include code snippets. I don't know if I'd technically be wanting a fixed height hardcoded, but rather the UI to be able to determine which IconButtonRow is the tallest based on the content that resides in it and make every other IconButtonRow that height as well. I could technically add a height parameter to the IconButtonRow but I would need to know what the max height for a given row based on its content. Second, I'm not using a grid but I could certainly try. I don't know if that would result in overflow if the user's font size is huge

by fixed height, its not hard coded at all, the childAspectRatio will give it a particular ratio which will be well dynamic in nature. I strongly feel, the requirement here is a GridView. Flutter offers numerous types of GridView, which worth a try.

Just implemented it to be stored in a grid and I can see that every "row" within the grid is the same height, but there are still issues with overflow when the user sets their phone's font size to be huge (pictured https://imgur.com/a/overflow-example-GmdvIOU)

That font management is a different use case altogether. You may find out the solution here. I believe this is a great to have fix for all Flutter Apps.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59143443/how-to-make-flutter-app-font-size-independent-from-device-settings
Hope this helps

Because each button icon and spacing size is predetermined, only the text varied and make layout inconsistent, We can calculate the space each text occupied, then take the longest text height and set that height for every button, we can use TextPainter to do just that.
My simplified button model:
class IconButtonRow {
  final String title;

  IconButtonRow({required this.title});
}

final buttons = [
  IconButtonRow(title: "the"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "quick"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "brown"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "fox"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "jumped\nto\nthe\nnext\nline"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "over"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "the"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "lazy"),
  IconButtonRow(title: "dog"),
];


Then we get max height for those button, keep in mind that inside TextSpan, you must use the same text, same styling and same scale factor as the ui text:

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double maxHeight = 0;
    for (var element in buttons) {
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textScaler: MediaQuery.of(context).textScaler,
        text: TextSpan(
            text: element.title,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 10,
              height: 1,
            )),
      )..layout(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3);
      // layout before calculate height
      final height = textPainter.height;
      if (height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = height;
      }
    }
/// Now we can build the ui with predetermined height
...

Then you can build the ui, just wrap button text inside any size constraint
widget with height = maxHeight and they are all occupied the same space. You can use Row + Column, or Wrap,... doesn't matter, you already know how big your button should be. I use GridView in this case:
...
/// continue with the `build()` method
    return Scaffold(
        body: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: buttons.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        mainAxisExtent: 50 + maxHeight,
        crossAxisSpacing: 8,
        mainAxisSpacing: 8,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
            ),
            Text(
              buttons[index].title,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
                height: 1,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}


Result:

Update: you need to specify maxWidth when laying out text, if not it will assume the widget width
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      ...
    )..layout(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3);



This did EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you so much for this answer and helping out, it's greatly appreciated!
